# How can I delete a column in sheet 2 based on sheet 1?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two different sheets: "Input"(sheet2) and "Instruction"(Sheet1)

I want to delete the whole column in "Input" sheet corresponding to the value in the cell(row 34, column 2) of "Instruction"(Sheet1) in .

I tried this following code and it does not work. I could not find the problem.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

  mykeyword1 = Worksheets("Instruction").Cells(34, 2).Value
  
  For i = 1 To 20
      If Worksheets("Input").Cells(1, i).Value = mykeyword1 Then
            
      Worksheets("Input").Activate
      Worksheets("Input").Cells(Rows.Count, i).Clear
      
       End If
       
       Next       
End Sub
```

Please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbibs.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your post & share the method/VBA code you have tried so far,, will help us to  improve it to achieve the goal !!

Comment: Already did. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just changed the code and it works in this case

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  mykeyword1 = Worksheets("Instruction").Cells(34, 2).Value
  
  
  For i = 1 To 20
       If Worksheets("Input").Cells(1, i).Value = mykeyword1 Then
      
      
            'Worksheets("Input").Activate
            Worksheets("Input").Columns(i).Clear
      
         End If
       
       Next
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Hope this is working for U !